# Deleting Classic Google Sites pages via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Is there a way to delete large sections of a classic Site via Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* CHANGE THE URL BELOW TO THE PAGE THAT YOU WANT TO DELETE. THEN SELECT "Run" > "deletePage" ABOVE. */

const URL = 'https://sites.google.com/site/demositeappsscript/mylistpage';



/* DON'T MODIFY ANYTHING BELOW HERE. */

function deletePage() {
  const pageToDelete = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(URL);
  deletePageHelper_(pageToDelete);
}

function deletePageHelper_(page) {
  page.getChildren().forEach(childPage => deletePageHelper_(childPage));
  Logger.log(`DELETING PAGE: "${page.getName()}".`);
  page.deletePage();
}
```